# C++ ESP32 adc2_get_raw speed improvement

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++, adc

I try to do some measurements of the speed of sound with an esp32 and two microphones. I placed the microphones a meter away from each other and try to detect bang on them.

I would love to get at leas 35 Samples per millisecond but stuck on 25,34. My code looks like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <driver/adc.h>
#include <esp_system.h>

#define MEASUREMENTS 30000
int measurements1[MEASUREMENTS]; // Globales Array
int measurements2[MEASUREMENTS]; // Globales Array

class Stereomic {
  public:
    Stereomic(adc1_channel_t ad1, adc2_channel_t ad2) {
      adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12);
      adc1_config_channel_atten(ad1, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11); 
      adc2_config_channel_atten(ad2, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11); 
    }

    void runMeasurement() {
      unsigned long start_time = millis();

      for (int i = 0; i < MEASUREMENTS; ++i) {
        measurements1[i] = adc1_get_raw(ADC1_CHANNEL_6);
        adc2_get_raw(ADC2_CHANNEL_3,ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12, &measurements2[i]);
      }

      unsigned long end_time = millis();
      unsigned long elapsed_time_ms = end_time - start_time;
      Serial.printf("Time needed for measurement: %lu Milliseconds\n", elapsed_time_ms);
      Serial.printf("is %f Measurements per ms. Goal: 35 Messungen pro ms (Actual best 25.34/ms)\n", ((float)MEASUREMENTS / (float)elapsed_time_ms));
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setCpuFrequencyMhz( 240);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println("Start");
    Serial.println("Press Enter to start measurement...");
    Serial.read();

    Stereomic mic(ADC1_CHANNEL_6, ADC2_CHANNEL_3);
    mic.runMeasurement();
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

I know, it's not the best way to do this. It's a first try with equipment I have at home. Do you think it would be better to try it on a FM4 Starter Kit Microcontroller?

Thanks for your help!

(Current ESP32 board: WiFi Kit 32 (V3))